# ask about android xml

Tags: android, xml

i am download example android application

then file xml ini below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <net.example.view
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="346dp"
        android:layout_weight="79.81"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16pt" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i want to ask about this xml

```
 <net.example.view
       android:id="@+id/view"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="10" />
```

what xml above mean and what purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a custom View.

Custom Views can be defined in a Java class that extends an existing View, and can then be used in layout XML.

You can read more about them (and learn how to create your own) in the [Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) section of the Android Developers guide.